# I want to display data based on list group items

Tags: reactjs

App.jsx this my app.jsx

```
const pilihKategori = (event) => {
  const fileteredProduk = produk.filter((item) => 
    item.category.nama.includes(event.target.dataset.value)
  )
  setProduk(fileteredProduk)  
  console.log(event.target.dataset.value)
}
```

ListCategories.jsx

```
<Col md={2} mt="2">
        <h4><strong>Daftar Kategori</strong></h4>
        <hr />
        {props.categories?.map((item, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            <ListGroup>
              <ListGroup.Item onClick={props.pilihKategori} data-value={item.nama}>{item.nama}</ListGroup.Item>
            </ListGroup>
          </div>
        ))}
      </Col>
```

This is the result but when the second click it doesn't work:

[at first it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDqQp.png)

[and then this happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfaMs.png)

Comment: On first click it may filter the produks-list and set that filtered-list to the produk state based on the 'clicked-value'. Now produk contains filtered list. On second-click it agains filter the produks state. But produk state contains earlier filtered list, not the full produk-list. You should filter the full produk-list.